# How many different ways are there from $(0,0,0)$ to the point $(4,3,5)$?

Tags: combinatorics

I had an exam in my *introduction to combinatorics* lectures today, there was a question like this:

> In the $3D$ space, consider the points of integer coordinates. Using only moviments corresponding to the increment of $1$ in each of the coordinates at a time, how many different ways are there from $(0,0,0)$ to the point $(4,3,5)$?
>
> *In this question, once one step was given in one of the three directions, it can't be undone. The question doesn't seems to point this, at least in the original version I had in the test. Otherwise it would be possible to have infinite ways to the mentioned point.*

I've used the following reasoning:

It is mandatory that $4$ steps should be made in one direction, that $5$ steps should be made in another direction and that $3$ steps should be made in the other direction. With this in mind, It's possible to write arbitrary words with $3$ $D_1$'s, $4$ $D_2$'s, and $5$ $D_3$'s as in:

$$D_1,D_1,D_1,D_2,D_2,D_2,D_2,D_3,D_3,D_3,D_3,D_3,$$

Then it reduces to a problem of permuting the letters and removing the repetitions, therefore the answer is $\displaystyle \frac{12!}{3!4!5!}$. Is that correct?

Comment: "[Increment](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/increment)" means to increase (by 1), so the question does specify that there are no backward movements.

Comment: @ChrisCulter Yes. But as I say, I changed it a bit (and continued afraid of didn't have made my point clearly), then I added the note. In the test, it's not so clear like I wrote.

Comment: Yes this is correct. It's actually a case of the multinomial theorem, which is a generalisation of the binomial theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming (as you have) that all the steps need to be in a positive direction in one axis, so it will take exactly $12$ steps to get there, you are correct.  That seems to be the spirit of the problem.